# iOS AudioUnit v3 not visible on iPad2 simulator

Tags: ios, audiounit

I'd like to create an AudioUnit v3 as an extension for iOS 9.0

So, I watched the video from WWDC 2015 from there: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/508/

downloaded the sample code from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioUnitV3Example/Introduction/Intro.html

and built and ran it in Xcode7 successfully.

Everything looked fine, the plugin FilterDemo was visible as an extension in iPad Air, Air2 and Pro simulators. But neither in iPad2 nor iPad Retina.

All simulators are working on iOS 9.2, I'm not changing anything in the sample project, but the effect is not visible as an extension on some devices.

Following code:

```
let allEffects = AVAudioUnitComponentManager.sharedAudioUnitComponentManager().componentsMatchingDescription(AudioComponentDescription());

print(NSString(format:"Effects size %d", allEffects.count));
```

gives the result of 35 (default non v3 AUs) on iPad2 and Retina, and 36 for newer iPads (36th is the DEMO plugin defined in the tutorial).

The FilterDemo app itself is accessible on every iPad2+, so it's not a matter of architecture (armv7 vs armv7s etc..)

Does that mean v3 AU's are device-dependent, not iOS-dependent?

Any suggestions? Documentation hints?

Answer (score 1):

For AUv3 on iOS you'll need a iPad4 / iPhone5 or newer.